# How to set up in Custom Map (xaml, xamarin forms) your own position?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to set up in Custom Map (xaml) your own position? e.g. Warsaw

```
 <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" Margin="2" IsShowingUser="true" MapClicked="OnMapClicked">

        </local:CustomMap>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your *CustomMap* is inheriting from **Xamarin.Forms.Maps** class, then you need to set a [**MapSpan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps.mapspan?view=xamarin-forms) property.
Here how it is in xaml (I have added the coordinates for Warsaw):

```
<local:CustomMap>
    <x:Arguments>
        <maps:MapSpan>
            <x:Arguments>
                <maps:Position>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>52.2297</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>21.0122</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </maps:Position>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
        </maps:MapSpan>
    </x:Arguments>
</local:CustomMap>
```

Note: You can adjust the second & third parameter, which currently are set to 0.01 degrees, to better scale the span (they are the latitudeDegrees & longitudeDegrees).

Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map#display-a-specific-location-on-a-map